# Gridllines on only the left axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import pylab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

pyplotParams = {
    'backend': 'eps',
    'axes.labelsize': 8,
    'axes.facecolor': '#E5E5E5',  # axes background color
    'axes.edgecolor': 'k',        # axes edge  color
    'axes.grid': True,            # display grid or not
    'axes.axisbelow': True,       # show grid below plot elements
    'grid.color': 'w',            # grid color
    'grid.linestyle': '-',        # grid line style
    'figure.dpi': 80,
    'figure.facecolor': 'w',
 }

 rcParams.update(pyplotParams) 
 fig1 = plt.figure()
 ax4 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
 ax4.plot(xaxis3_val,cum_ar_250_ret,color='g')
 ax4.plot(xaxis3_val,cum_basket_250_ret,color='b')
 ax5 = ax4.twinx()
 ax5.plot(xaxis3_val,signal,color='r')
 plt.show()
```

In the above example is a cutdown version of a set of 4 plots and I want
gridlines on all four plots. However on figure 4, I want gridliness only for
ax4 and not ax5. The Axes object (ax5) does not seem to have an easy way to set
the printing of the grid to be turned off.
How can I selectively turn off the gridlines for ax5? I tried the following
but it does not work:

```
(Pdb) ax5.get_xgridlines()
<a list of 6 Line2D xgridline objects>
(Pdb) ax5.grid(ls=None)
*** AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
(Pdb)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need to turn the grid off. ([doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.grid))

```
ax5.grid(False)
```

Comment: That works, thanks! It is not very clear from the docs. grid method seems to have so many options and that is why I tried to set ls=None to clear the line style.

Comment: if you wanted to do it the way you were trying you should use `''` or `'none'`, `None` is used as a flag to say 'use the default value'.  The fact that it blows up like that looks like a bug to me.